# PHP: array_diff count issue due to multiple similar name

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

How can match similar words in array_diff count

Problem of multiple name for single words like TV-Television,Inches-Inch,Mobile-Mobile Phones,Mobile-Phones.So create wrong percentage in array_diff count

**Example :**

```
    $str1 = "Samsung Television 21 Inches LED BH005DE";
    $str2 = "Samsung 21 Inch LED TV";

    $arr1 = explode(' ', $str1);
    $arr2 = explode(' ', $str2);

    $differenceCount = count(array_diff($arr2, $arr1));
```

In above str1 and str2 contain **Television,TV** and **Inches,Inch** words..How can solve this problem

Comment: What is the expected result? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AmalMurali  match television and TV words

Comment: @Melody You are asking for the impossible, there are so many words with abbreviations and short forms, how is the system supposed to be aware of them? This isn't something you can solve with one or two functions, build up a database with all the possible scenarios (i.e. same words in different format).

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I asking for any algorithm or method(function) where we can insert few word which frequently used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way is to use synonyms for that:

```
$str1 = "Samsung Television 21 Inches LED BH005DE";
$str2 = "Samsung 21 Inch LED TV";

//synonyms:
$syns = [
   'TV'   => ['TV', 'Television'],
   'Inch' => ['Inch', 'Inches']
];

//replace:
$str1 = array_reduce(array_keys($syns), function($c, $x) use ($syns)
{
   return $c = preg_replace('/\b'.join('\b|\b', $syns[$x]).'\b/', $x, $c);
}, $str1);
//now, str1 looks like "Samsung TV 21 Inch LED BH005DE"

$str2 = array_reduce(array_keys($syns), function($c, $x) use ($syns)
{
   return $c = preg_replace('/\b'.join('\b|\b', $syns[$x]).'\b/', $x, $c);
}, $str2);
//now, str2 looks like "Samsung 21 Inch LED TV"

$arr1 = explode(' ', $str1);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $str2);


//var_dump(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));//['BH005DE']
```

In your case you can't rely on some sort of word forms (like `Inch` - `Inches`) - because you need to parse abbreviations too - and those are cases with specific meanings. Thus, using synonyms may be the only way to resolve the matter for all cases.

Comment: above code working on localhost but not working in server .....anything want to enable for above code ??? ...................I am using 5.4.26 PHP version on server and 5.4.12 on localhost

Comment: What's your error? (place `error_reporting(-1);` as a first line of script)

Comment: PHP Warning:  array_reduce() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given

Comment: That's odd, because has nothing to do with PHP version. It indicates that you're passing invalid handler for `array_reduce()` - and that is replacement closure in this case. Are you sure you're pasting whole code correctly?

Comment: **same code try in localhost and server** ........localhost gives array output ........but server gives blank array output

Comment: Hm, no ideas yet (since it's [working fine](http://3v4l.org/d7csn) with PHP 5.4+). I may suppose that it isn't allowed to define callbacks such way in your server, but that can only be possible in PHP<=5.2 (and, besides, that would raise fatal error, not warning)

Comment: ohk...no problem bro ... i do anything...thnx for give great support

Comment: can possible to change above code for other way ...like create function with argument....return function value..